# Tensorflow 1.1 Error : Attempt to reuse RNNCell with a different variable scope than its first use

Tags: deep-learning, python-3.5, tensorflow

I am trying to run the [seq2seq translate example](https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/seq2seq) present on Tensorflow website and getting following error. I am using `tensorflow-gpu==1.1.0`

> ValueError: Attempt to reuse RNNCell
>    with a different variable scope than its first use.
>   First use of cell was with scope
>   'embedding_attention_seq2seq/embedding_attention_decoder/attention_decoder/gru_cell',
>   this attempt is with scope 'embedding_attention_seq2seq/rnn/gru_cell'.
>   Please create a new instance of the cell if you would like it to use a
>   different set of weights.  If before you were using:
>   MultiRNNCell([GRUCell(...)] * num_layers), change to:
>   MultiRNNCell([GRUCell(...) for _ in range(num_layers)]).  If before
>   you were using the same cell instance as both the forward and reverse
>   cell of a bidirectional RNN, simply create two instances (one for
>   forward, one for reverse).  In May 2017, we will start transitioning
>   this cell's behavior to use existing stored weights, if any, when it
>   is called with scope=None (which can lead to silent model degradation,
>   so this error will remain until then.)

On github people were suggesting to change the add the `reuse` argument to cell as follows :

```py
def single_cell():
    return tf.contrib.rnn.GRUCell(size, reuse = tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)
if use_lstm:
    def single_cell():
        return tf.contrib.rnn.BasicLSTMCell(size, reuse = tf.get_variable_scope().reuse)
    cell = single_cell()
if num_layers > 1:
    cell = tf.contrib.rnn.MultiRNNCell([single_cell() for _ in range(num_layers)])
```

But still I am getting the same error. What's the issue and how to resolve it ? 
Any help is highly appreciated.

P.S: A similar post was there on stackoverflow,but that solution didn't work for me and since the version of TF is different, I created a new post.

Comment: Can you create a minimal example that still throws this error (and show us) of how you are defining your cells with their scopes? Are you defining scope manually?

Comment: @Engineero I am learning TF right now and this is my first example which I am trying. I just cloned from TF/models. Link to code : https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/tutorials/rnn/translate

Comment: @Engineero Hey,  Can u pls help me in resolving this ?

Comment: I'm really not sure. I will try to look at it more soon.